# Bounds on the Christoffel symbols in normal coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a smooth closed Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with injectivity radius $i_M$ I can choose for every $x \in M$ an orthonormal basis of $T_x M$ and a normal coordinate system $ \phi$ in $x$, such that the Christoffel symbols satisfy
$$
(\Gamma^k_{ij})_x(0)=0.
$$
By differentiability we have for $p \in B_{i_M}(0)$
$$
|(\Gamma^k_{ij})_x(p)| \leq |p| \sup_{p \in B_{i_M}(0)} |D(\Gamma^k_{ij})(p)|
$$
How can I bound $\sup_{p \in B_{i_M}(0)}|D(\Gamma^k_{ij})(p)|$ in terms of the curvature tensor $R$ of $(M,g)$?
I found that the Christoffel symbols satisfy 
$$
\Gamma^k_{ij,l} = -\frac{1}{3} ( R^k_{jkl} + R^k_{kjl}).
$$
Does this imply that
$$
\sup_{p \in B_{i_M}(0)} |D(\Gamma^k_{ij})(p)| \leq \sup_{p \in B_{i_M}(0)} \sup_{ijkl}  R^k_{jkl}(\phi^{-1}(p)).
$$

Comment: You can express the curvature tensor in terms of Christoffel symbols, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor .

Comment: But how can I use the equality $R^\ell{}_{ijk}=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \Gamma^\ell{}_{ik}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\Gamma^\ell{}_{ij}
+\Gamma^\ell{}_{js}\Gamma_{ik}^s-\Gamma^\ell{}_{ks}\Gamma^s{}_{ij}$ to find an estimate?

Comment: What makes you think this is possible? You can have very nonzero Christoffel symbols with $R=0$ — isn't polar coordinates on the plane going to give you an example?